# Filling values (like in excel) based on previous row in R

Tags: r

My question is what package should I use to fill down new rows like in excel or does that require a loop?

For example, if my data DF1 is

```
Dates      aa     bb
2000 q1    1      2
2000 q2    2      3
2000 q3    3      4
```

Then I want to find the next 3 quarters and I have its growth rate in DF2:

```
Dates      aa_g     bb_g
2000 q4    0.1      0.2
2001 q1    0.2      0.2
2001 q2    0.3      0.3
```

The final table I would like to generate is:

```
Dates      aa     bb
2000 q1    1      2
2000 q2    2      3
2000 q3    3      4
2000 q4    3.3    4.8
2001 q1    3.96   5.8
2001 q2    5.15   7.5
```

The results I would replicate in excel is easy and basically last row of DF1*(1+growth rate row (DF2) and drag it down. In r, to generate new rows depending on the previous value, would I need to first create a new data frame with dates and NA write a loop for it or is there an easier way?

Thanks!
Here are some code to create the small df above:

```
Dates=seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2000/9/1"), by = "quarter")
aa= seq(1,3)
bb= seq(2,4)
df1<-data.frame(Dates,aa,bb)

Dates=seq(as.Date("2000/12/1"), as.Date("2001/6/1"), by = "quarter")
aa_g= seq(0.1,0.3, by=0.1)
bb_g= c(0.2,0.2,0.3)
df2<-data.frame(Dates,aa_g,bb_g)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one base R approach :

```
#Take last row of df1
a <- df1[nrow(df1), -1]
#Calculate cumulative product of df2 and multiply it with last row of df1
df2[-1] <- sweep(sapply(df2[-1], function(x) cumprod(1 + x)), 2, unlist(a), `*`)
#Assign names of df1 to df2
names(df2) <- names(df1)
#Combine the two dataframes
result <- rbind(df1, df2)
result

#       Dates    aa    bb
#1 2000-01-01 1.000 2.000
#2 2000-04-01 2.000 3.000
#3 2000-07-01 3.000 4.000
#4 2000-12-01 3.300 4.800
#5 2001-03-01 3.960 5.760
#6 2001-06-01 5.148 7.488
```

Comment: thanks ronak! very cool, cumprod definitely does the job. can you explain what the unlist (a), '*' at the end does?

Comment: 3rd argument to `sweep` needs a vector, `a` is a dataframe so I `unlist` it to make it a vector and `*` is used to multiple `df2` and `a` rowwise.